# why is my datalist displaying incorrectly in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, angular, input, datalist

On the login page of a web application that we are building in Angular2, in Chrome Version 55.0.2883.87 m, the datalist is displaying odd behaviour.

This happens on the first event fire, so if you start typing, it will be on the first keydown event, and the list will move on the following event. It does the same on click and focus. The datalist displays as it should in Edge, Opera, and Firefox. My colleagues who have all merged that branch have not encountered the issue at all, which is why I believe it may be a browser issue.

You can see the difference between the first and second events here.

[image]

**The HTML:**

```
<input list="user-name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ 'SIGN.USERNAME' | translate }}" required autofocus [(ngModel)]="localUser.username">
<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ 'SIGN.PASSWORD' | translate }}" required [(ngModel)]="localUser.password">
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-color" (click)="login();" id="login-button" [ngClass]="{'login-error': loginFailed}">
    {{ loginText }}
</button>

<datalist id="user-name">
    <option value={{user}} *ngFor="let user of pastLoggedInUsers">
</datalist>
```

Can anyone shed some light as to whether this is a browser bug, or if there is something we can do in code to resolve the issue?

Comment: I didn't quite get what you mean by "This happens on the first event fire, so if you start typing, it will be on the first keydown event, and the list will move on the following event." ,

Comment: @Milad In the image above, if I type 'j' the datalist displays incorrectly, but when I consequently type 'e' the datalist moves. So, from the second keydown event, the datalist behaves as it should. Apologies if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: It might not be related , but you should put value="{{user}}"  ( double quotation"

Comment: Thanks for the tip; gave it a try but sadly, no luck.

Comment: I don't see anything weird , could you inspect your chrome and take a screen shot of the compiled element there and put it here ?

Comment: I've heard bizarre behaviours being reported because of using {{}} ( interpolation in attributes . ) I know safari have some issues , this might be somehow related as well, so I'd suggest get rid of all of them and use the correct syntax

Comment: And by correct syntax I mean : [value]="user"   ------ [attr.placeholder]=" SIGN.PASSWORD | translate"

Comment: I have updated the syntax just to be sure, but the behaviour is still the same.  Here is the compiled source from the inspector: http://imgur.com/a/LsQ2D

Comment: Dude, I tested in my chrome , 55.0.2883.95 , it's working properly for me. Looks like it's just for that version, upgrade your chrome to my version to see if issue goes away, if it didn't , you're probably doing something with css that causes this issue, I can't think of anything else :) have fun

Comment: For my OS I can't upgrade to that version :/ but thanks, I will have a look in the css. Thanks for you help